# Matrix-free linear solve for nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm looking for an algorithm to solve for the classic:

$$A\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$$

I cannot compute $A$ directly, but rather can compute matrix-vector products $A\mathbf{v}$ for any $\mathbf{v}$.

At first, this appears to be a straightforward application of matrix-free solvers.  Since I don't have any guarantees on symmetry or positive-definitness, this seems like a good application of the [BICGSTAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconjugate_gradient_stabilized_method) algorithm.

The only problem is that I am interested in the special case where $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{0}$, i.e. solving for the a vector in the nullsapce of $A$.  Obviously, the trivial vector $\mathbf{x}$ = $\mathbf{0}$ is a solution, but not an interesting or useful one.  Unfortunately, it's also one that matrix-free methods are prone to find.
(It's also the min-norm solution, which I think is problematic as some solutions search for the min-norm solution.)

Is there any trick I can use to extract a non-trivial solution $\mathbf{x}$ with a matrix-free solver for general $A$?

Comment: You can have a look at the QR decomposition of $A^T$ which should give you a basis of the nullspace of $A$.

Comment: Are there any matrix-free ways of computing the QR decomposition?

Comment: If the matrix is symmetric, you can shift the spectrum by adding a multiple of the identity, so that the eigenvalue that was zero now becomes the largest magnitude eigenvalue. Then use lanczos, or randomized svd or what have you to compute the largest eigenpair. The performance of this approach depends on how big the spectral gap is between zero and the smallest eigenvalue; bigger gap is better

Comment: In order to do this, wouldn't I need to know the eigenvalues beforehand?  Seems a bit chicken-and-egg?  I also would have to double-check, but I don't think I have symmetry guarantees.

Comment: You can do $\rho I - A^TA$, where $\rho > \lambda_\text{max}$, where $\lambda_\text{max}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$. You can find $\lambda_\text{max}$ via Lanczos or even power iteration

Comment: Can you write out a full algorithm in an answer?  I now get the computation of $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ but the rest is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Oh, but if this method requires a symmetric matrix, then it is not suitable for my case.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410566/matrix-free-linear-solve-for-nullspace